imagewebp cause PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time
I'm havng sometimes this problem
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time .. line N
The number of the line N is the line with imagewebp() function
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(TMP_UPLOAD_PATH . $filename));

$done=imagewebp($img,TMP_UPLOAD_PATH . $file_only.'.webp');

On linux php 8 server
If a restart script, it is ok
I don't want to extend the time_execution
My script analys a lot of webp image (maybe >1000)
Anyone could have an idea ?
I try to add a try {} catch {} but this done nothing better
try {
   $done=imagewebp($img,TMP_UPLOAD_PATH . $file_only.'.webp');
}
catch (Exception $e){
   $done=false;
}


My script analys a lot of webp image...this could be a time-consuming operation. Not much you can do about it, except maybe restructure your script so it only processes a smaller number of images at a time, and then re-runs later to process some more. Are you currently running this via a web request, or as a background task?

Maximum execution time is a setting, and you can change it to your liking. If set low, you expect response to be fast. But I wouldn't expect manipulating thousands of images to be fast. Command-line PHP (which you would normally use for this kind of task) typically doesn't have this limit enabled. Also, you can catch exceptions (being precise, "throwables"), and a fatal error (or a warning or a notice) is not an exception.
